# C#: Adding Paths to Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvass that is 200 pixels wide and 100 pixels tall.  I then have 4 squares that are arranged in a checker board type fashion:

```
 -- --
|  |  |
 -- --
|  |  |
 -- --
```

The pixel coordinate of the bottom left square is 300,300; so its outside of the canvas's view.  I have 2 questions:

1) What is the best way to added these 4 squares to the canvas?  This is how I've been doing it.

```
Path p = new Path();
p.Fill = Blue;
p.Data = Square[0];

canvas.Children.Add(p);
```

2)  How do I change the viewing range of the canvas to "move" to where its children are actually drawn?

I can't get this to work, but I can get two sort of working results.  The first is where I just draw the the squares and add a transform that scales them really small. This results in the shapes being viewable in the canvas but they aren't centered or zoomed nicely.

The second case is where they get added all on top of each other but are centered.  This happens when I set teh Stretch value of the path.

I basically want to add a set of Geometry objects to a canvas and have the canvas's view move to focus on its children's bounding box.  How do I do this programatically in C#.  This is easy enough to do in XAML if you hardcode the shapes, but in my case I want to know how to scale and zoom automatically for any given shape and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of adding shapes in code-behind looks absolutely fine to me. To move the `Canvas` to 'focus' on a particular area is not something that it does automatically for you. However, you can add a `TranslateTransform` to move the children:

```
canvas.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform () { X = 100, Y=-100 };
```